# how to get user select invalid date in 3 selects eg 29 February 2017 or 31 September 2017 in php?

Tags: php, date

I Have 3 `<select>` in html from to select date

- First  is for date (1-31)
- Second  is for month (1-12)
- Third  if for year 1990 - 2018

How can in get in php that user selected invalid date. Such as 31 September 2017 or 29 Febraury 2014 etc.
Thanks

Comment: I would do this in Javascript, but tell us, what have you tried so far? Show us some code to work with.

Comment: if i select 31 September 2017, it made it 1 October 2017. and if i select 30 February, it makes it 2 March

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit long winded doing this with any form of validation like Javascript or PHP.

I would recommend Javascript and there is a source to read from here:

https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/javascript-date-validation.php

However why not just change your SELECT statement to this:

```
<input type="date" name="date" required />
```

This removes any need to check the date is valid, works on all browsers, is mobile friendly...etc. and if you need to you can add on more controls like must be in future or only so many days from now...etc. relatively simply.

Comment: That is a good idea, but it doesn't show selectors in my browser, just a text field. I would consider that less user friendly.

Comment: its shows text field, it dont have selectors